# Missing elements in autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm playing around with coordinates in autodesk forge and by some chance i noticed that some of the element(door in my case) doesn't have an fragment id. I've tried to use selection and fittoview to try and display which is the problematic element and to my surprise the element doesnt even exist in the viewer (I still managed to use getProperties to show all the properties though).
Is this because of some bug occurred during the conversion from revit to forge or is it because of an error in my programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be expected that small objects get lost in Revit export processes, cf.:

- [Model objects missing in custom exporter context](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/some-model-missing-when-in-customer-export-iexportcontext-revit/m-p/8061762)
- [Small objects missing in DWG export](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-architecture-forum/export-to-dwg-small-objects-missing/td-p/7387089)

How large is your missing door? How large is the model?

Comment: I've looked through the model in revit and it seems like a good portion of the model is cut in forge viewer and also in bim360. I'm gonna assume that there's an error during the upload.